# choropleth plotly map displaying a white background

Tags: plotly-python, choropleth

I am trying to create a choropleth map of the uk using plotly, but every time I try, it outputs an empty page, or the json doesn't match with the dataframe.[this is where i obtained the url for the dataframe](https://coronavirus.data.gov.uk/details/download) Here's my code so far:

```
import pandas as pd
from urllib.request import urlopen
import json
with urlopen('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/deldersveld/topojson/master/countries/united-kingdom/uk-counties.json') as response:
    geojson = json.load(response)

url3 = 'https://api.coronavirus.data.gov.uk/v2/data?areaType=utla&metric=cumCasesBySpecimenDate&metric=cumPeopleVaccinatedFirstDoseByVaccinationDate&metric=cumPeopleVaccinatedSecondDoseByVaccinationDate&metric=newCasesBySpecimenDate&metric=cumPeopleVaccinatedThirdInjectionByVaccinationDate&format=csv'

df = pd.read_csv(url3)
df_new=df.replace("areaName", "NAME_2")


from plotly import graph_objects as go

fig = go.Figure(
    go.Choroplethmapbox(
                geojson=geojson,
                featureidkey="properties.NAME_2",
                locations=df["areaCode"],
                z=df['cumCasesBySpecimenDate'],
                zauto=True,
                colorscale='Reds',
                showscale=True,
         
    )
)

fig.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

a few things to fix this up:

1. uk-counties.json is in topojson format, plotly needs a geojson. can fix with the topojson module, for example (or geopandas)
2. no need to replace "areaName", you want this: locations=df["areaName"]
3. you need to specify a marker_style. centering and zooming help as well
4. for good result you need to use only one day's worth of data per choropleth, hence the df = df[df['date'] == '2022-11-23']
5. the covid data and the topojson don't match up well by districts, so there are gaps in the map

code:

```
"""
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71828342/choropleth-plotly-map-displaying-a-white-background
"""

from urllib.request import urlretrieve
import json
from io import StringIO

from plotly import graph_objects as go
import pandas as pd
import topojson as tp

URL_JSON = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/deldersveld/topojson/master/countries/united-kingdom/uk-counties.json'

URL_DATA = 'https://api.coronavirus.data.gov.uk/v2/data?areaType=utla&metric=cumCasesBySpecimenDate&metric=cumPeopleVaccinatedFirstDoseByVaccinationDate&metric=cumPeopleVaccinatedSecondDoseByVaccinationDate&metric=newCasesBySpecimenDate&metric=cumPeopleVaccinatedThirdInjectionByVaccinationDate&format=csv'

CSV_DATA = 'uk_covid.csv'
TOPO_DATA = 'topojson.json'
GEO_DATA = 'geojson.json'


def download():
    urlretrieve(URL_JSON, TOPO_DATA)
    with open(TOPO_DATA, 'r') as data:
        topoJSON = json.load(StringIO(data.read()))

    topo = tp.Topology(topoJSON, object_name='GBR_adm2')
    # convert to geojson, store in GEO_DATA
    topo.to_geojson(GEO_DATA)

    df = pd.read_csv(URL_DATA)
    df.to_csv(CSV_DATA)


def make_map():
    df = pd.read_csv(CSV_DATA)

    with open(GEO_DATA, 'r') as data:
        geojson = json.load(StringIO(data.read()))

    # one day at a time
    df = df[df['date'] == '2022-11-23']

    fig = go.Figure(
        go.Choroplethmapbox(
            geojson=geojson,
            featureidkey="properties.NAME_2",
            locations=df["areaName"],  # <=== not areaCode
            z=df['cumCasesBySpecimenDate'],
            zauto=True,
            colorscale='Reds',
            showscale=True
        )
    )

    # need a mapbox_style
    fig.update_layout(mapbox_style='carto-positron',
                      mapbox_zoom=5,
                      mapbox_center_lon=-2.057852,
                      mapbox_center_lat=53.404854,
                      height=700,
                      width=700)

    fig.show()


if 0:   # only needed once
    download()

make_map()
```